# Ajax call (b) within callback of another ajax call (a) executes before (a) completes

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, callback

I have an ajax call, let's say callback (b), within the callback of another ajax call, let's say callback (a). In my code (b) depends on the success of ajax call (a). However, contrary to what I expected, ajax call (b) still completes successfully before the parent ajax call (a) completes.

**Javascript**

```
var ajaxAdata; //global

ajaxA(ajaxB(1));

function ajaxA(callback){
       FB.api('/me', function(response) { //ajax call(a)
            ajaxAdata = response.id; 
            callback(); // this completes before ajax call(a) completes
       }
}

ajaxB = function(isPublic) {
       .getJSON(){ //ajax call (b)
            console.log(ajaxAdata); // necessary ajaxAdata returns undefined
        }
}
```

Am I ignorant of something in regards to javascript here? I've read in many places that a callback function is the right way to handle asynch calls. In this case, does javascript still read ahead into the ajaxB function and starts to execute .getJSON() before the FB.api() call is complete?

Comment: where is ajaxB called?

Comment: I'm trying to call it as callback() in ajaxA.

Comment: Perfect, thank you all for the answers. The sequence of calls were as desired after the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ajaxA(ajaxB(1));
```

Is actually executing ajaxB,, and then using the result to pass as an argument to ajaxA.

You need to pass in the function, not the result.

So try

```
ajaxA(ajaxB);
```

Then, in ajaxA, pass in your argument to the callback with

```
callback(1);
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Is it always the case that if I pass in a function call with an argument within the parameter, such as `ajaxB(1)`, it will execute in that call? Because I know in `ajaxA(function(){...});` the anonymous function should not execute...

Comment: Yes, because specifying the argument of a defined function is the syntax for calling the function.  The closure you're creating doesn't include the calling syntax ( e.g. var func = function(arg) { console.log(arg); }("We are calling the closure here"); )

Comment: Any expression of the form `fun1(fun2(arg))` runs `fun2` first, and then runs `fun1` with its return value as the argument.

Comment: For instance `alert(parseInt("123"))` first calls `parseInt`, then calls `alert`.

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot about that in my attempt to shorten code.  My ajaxB function is large, so I did not want to pass an entire function as an argument in the parameter. I will take a look at my code again.

Answer (score 2):

Your call

```
ajaxA(ajaxB(1));
```

executes `ajaxB(1)` before `ajaxA` is even invoked to provide the value of parameter for `ajaxA`.

It should be

```
ajaxA(ajaxB, 1);
```

and

```
function ajaxA(callback, param){
       FB.api('/me', function(response) { //ajax call(a)
            ajaxAdata = response.id; 
            callback(param); // this completes before ajax call(a) completes
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
ajaxA(function() {ajaxB(1);} );
```

You were calling `ajaxB()` first, and passing its return value (`undefined`) as the `callback` argument to `ajaxA()`. You want to pass a function that calls `ajaxB()` as the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing ajaxB here:

```
ajaxB(1)
```

I think what you want to do is either return a function from `ajaxB` or find a way to pass the `isPublic` flag to your ajaxA function like:

```
ajaxA(ajaxB, 1);

function ajaxA(callback, isPublic){
       FB.api('/me', function(response) { //ajax call(a)
            ajaxAdata = response.id; 
            callback(isPublic); // this completes before ajax call(a) completes
       }
}
```